# Consume WCF service in Xamarin.Forms PCL?

Tags: wcf, xamarin.forms

Is there a definitive way of consuming a WCF service in a Xamarin.Forms PCL (Portable) project?  From what I have researched so far, one possible solution that has been brought forth so far is using slsvcutil.exe to generate a client file, but I ran into a very large amount of errors when I added the file to my Xamarin.Forms (Portable) project.  Am I perhaps missing something here?

(Edit)
I think I may have at least partially answered my question.  It is possible to add WCF service references to the Portable project, however, you need to remove the Windows Phone 8 as a build target (not needed). I encountered the NUGet 3.0 opt-in error, so I went ahead and removed Xamarin.Forms temporarily to be able to change the target.  Once the target was changed, I saw the add Service Reference button.  I entered the URL of the desired service and clicked OK.  However, during the creation of the service files, Visual Studio crashes on me.  Any idea why VS 2015 would crash in the creation of the service reference?

Thanks

Comment: I found the cause of the crash!  Turns out that when you have .NET Core 1.0 selected, it crashes.  Well, I went ahead and removed .NET Core as a build target for now.  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/81817/bug-visual-studio-2015-going-to-crash-every-time-i-try-to-add-services-references-in-pcl-project

Comment: Does anyone know of the significance of having .NET Core 1.0 as a selectable target for Xamarin.Forms applications?  Does having .NET Core 1.0 allow for the creation of the UWP project for Windows 10?

Comment: I have removed .NET Core in my project and can still work with the UWP project in XF. I have also added the service reference to the PCL without problems. However I can't get the service to return any data - all methods return void so that's not much help.